# Variable interpolation inside printf-style formatting functions

Tags: objective-c, printf

Is there a way to pass a variable for the floating point precision parameter in printf-style string formatting functions in Objective-C (or even C)? For example, in TCL and other scripting languages, I can do something like this:

```
set precision 2
puts [format "%${precision}f" 3.14159]
```

and the output will be, of course, 3.14. I would like to do something similar in Objective-C:

```
float precision = 2
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".2f", 3.14159]
```

except that I would like to include precision as a variable. How can this be done?

Comment: You could use stringWithFormat twice: Once to assemble the format string and the second time to apply the created format to your value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the [string format specifiers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) for `printf`, which are used by Cocoa for formatting, include a variable-precision specifier, `*` placed after the decimal point:

```
int precision = 3;
NSLog(@"%.*f", precision, 3.14159);
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*f", precision, 3.14159];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by making your format string a variable, and then passing that to stringWithFormat, like this:

```
float precision = 2;
NSString* formatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%df", precision];
NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString, 3.14159];
```

The format string says you want a "%" symbol followed by a "." and then the value stored in the variable "precision" followed by "f".