# Construct a dynamic formatting string, for fixed width float values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, string-formatting

I have a class holding various types of numeric values. Within this class I have a couple of helper methods that are used to output descriptor text for display within my application.

This descriptor text should always appear as an integer or float, depending on the definition of the particular instance.

The class has a property, `DecimalWidth`, that I use to determine how many decimals to display. I need help writing a line of code that displays the numeric value, but with a fixed number of decimals, (0 is a possibility, and in such a case the value should be displayed as an integer.)

I am aware that I can could return a value like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", self.Value]` but my problem is that I need to replace the '2' in the format string with the value of `DecimalWidth`.

I can think of couple ways of solving this problem.  I could concat a string together and that is as the format string for the outputted string line.  Or, I could make a format string within a format string.

These solutions sound hideous and seem rather inefficient, but maybe these are the best options that I have.

Is there an elegant way of constructing a dynamic formatting string where the output is a fixed decimal width number but the specified decimal width is dynamic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable interpolation inside printf-style formatting functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761527/variable-interpolation-inside-printf-style-formatting-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However one solution for the problem is definitely question suggested by @lulius caesar,
But one good way is also using `NSNumberFormatter`. Below is a sample code you can use to generate decimal values with fixed decimal number

```
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:DecimalWidth];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:DecimalWidth];
    NSString * decimalString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.value]]]
```

Answer (score 5):

That doesn't sound hideous **or** inefficient to me.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%df", DecimalWidth], self.Value]
```

In fact I think it **is** rather elegant.