# String of float to an arbitrary decimal precision

Tags: objective-c

I want to write a method that takes a given float, a precision, and formats it such that it displays the given precision number of decimal places.

Of course, this method also does other bunch of things.

Right now, I have

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%.3f", s]; //s is the float argument
```

Which gives the string of the float to 3 decimal places. Now, I want to make it such that it has n decimal places. In effect, I want something like:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%.%if", n, s]; 
//n is the precision argument, s is the float argument
```

But for obvious reasons, it does not work.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable interpolation inside printf-style formatting functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761527/variable-interpolation-inside-printf-style-formatting-functions); you can also [use an `NSNumberFormatter`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337171/limiting-both-the-fractional-and-total-number-of-digits-when-formatting-a-float/10337518#10337518).

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I didn't really think it was relevant from the title though...that's why I missed it!

Comment: What you want can be done but it's a bad idea. You really should use an `NSNumberFormatter` so the number is formatted properly based in the user's locale.

Comment: I think it's all up to context. Here, I am formatting something completely irrelevant to user's locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `…"%.*f", n, s`. For more information, `stringWithFormat:` follows the [IEEE printf spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

Not sure what the `0` prefix is for in your original format string. You certainly don't need it as part of the format specification. If it's for zero padding up to, say, two digits, you should do something like `"%0*.*f", 3 + n, n, s`.

Comment: Forgot to specify that...it's part of converting a float in seconds to hh:mm:ss format except I require some arbitrary precision for the second component.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a star (`*`) as the precision width in the format string. `*` star signifies that the width will be specified as a variable in the variable arguments (before the variable to be printed). So

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%.*f", n, s];
```

Where `n` is an integer describing the width, and `s` is the floating point value.